# Open all hyperlinks in ionic capacitor app, inside the app itself, instead of opening in browser

Tags: angular, deep-linking, capacitor, ionic5

There are some hyperlinks in my ionic capacitor app which come from backend. If hyperlinks belong to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), I want them to open them inside the App using InAppBrowser or may be route it inside the app to that specific page.

I have deeplinking in my app. When I click on those links in app, the deeplink pop up comes to ask "open in app or in browser", but I want to always open those links in app.

tried in app.component.ts

```
initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.setupDeeplinks();
  });
}

setupDeeplinks() {
  this.deeplinks.route({
    '/page1/:id': 'Page1',
    '/page2/:id': 'Page2',
    // Add more route patterns for your pages
  }).subscribe(match => {
    // Match found, navigate to the respective page
    const page = match.$route;
    const params = match.$args;
    this.navigateToPage(page, params);
  }, nomatch => {
    // No match found for the given deep link
  });
}

navigateToPage(page: string, params: any) {
  // Logic to navigate to the respective page based on the route pattern
  // For example:
  switch (page) {
    case 'Page1':
      // Navigate to Page1 passing the necessary params
      // this.router.navigate(['/page1', params.id]);
      break;
    case 'Page2':
      // Navigate to Page2 passing the necessary params
      // this.router.navigate(['/page2', params.id]);
      break;
    // Add more cases for your pages
  }
}
```

but this didnt work